# Regarding updating pom file

Tags: maven, pom.xml, jacoco

I am working on a continuous integration tool and here i need to integrate jacoco plugin after checking out. I do not want to enforce developer to add jacoco plugin while checkin instead i would like to add it while running the jenkins based continuous integration tool.
Is it possible to achieve any of these options?:
1. to modify the pom file checked in by the developer and inject the dependency and plugin required for jacoco?

OR

2. to add the jacoco plugin super pom and mention that in jenkins configuration.

I tried this super pom approach, and it was reading super pom from a common repository, but not generating jacoco-exec file. I used below in super pom.

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    pom

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.6.201602180812</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.6.201602180812</version>
            <configuration>
                <destFile>${basedir}/target/jacoco-unit.exec</destFile>
                <dataFile>${basedir}/target/jacoco-unit.exec</dataFile>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate profile in the pom.xml, name it as jenkins profile and include jacoco plugin in that profile. You can then configure the mvn command in your jenkins job to include `-P jenkins_profile_name`. So the build would be done using the jenkins profile configuration.

Mark the existing profile as default and developers won't need to do anything specific.

For more details, refer to maven documentation for build profiles:

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Comment: Thanks for the response ritesh, i have one more question, in that case will it execute the jenkins_profile_name alone or will execute the project pom after jenkins_profile_name. Reason why i am asking is, jenkins_profile_name will have only say jacoco plugin and dependency and the other project pom will have all other dependencis. -P or -F will just execute that isnt it? Appreciated..

Comment: It depends on how you have configured your pom. If it is like this:

`<profiles>
<profile>
<id>jenkins</id>
<activation>
<activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
</activation>
<build>
<plugins>
.
.
<!-- Jacoco plugin -->
</plugins>
</build>
</profile>
<profile>
<id>default</id>
<activation>
<activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
</activation>
</profile>
</profiles>
<build>
<!-- Existing plugins and dependencies -->
</build>
`
The profiles will define the profile specific attributes for the project and build configuration would apply on both the profiles